# How can I upload high-res photos to Facebook from my iPad

Tags: ipad, photos.app, photos, facebook

I've bought the New iPad and have been using iPhoto to upload my pictures to Facebook. However, when I view them the quality doesn't look good. When browsed from the desktop Facebook site, the site does not provide a high quality version to download either.

How can I upload high quality images to Facebook from my iPad?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best way is to do it through Safari. As far as I know Safari doesn't change the size or quality of uploaded images.

Keep in mind that max size in pixels of an image on Facebook currently is limited to 2048x2048px. If you try to upload a bigger image Facebook will resize and reencode it automatically and the result will not be optimal.

Comment: Perfect! I just tested this answer out and from the mobile Facebook site on Safari for iOS I was able to upload an image at 2048x2048(or currently the max for FB). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. Was quality as good as you expected it to be?

Answer (score 2):

I uploaded a photo through Facebook, but it had bad quality, so I tried uploading it with iPhoto, and it did it with the highest quality. I also compared a the quality difference between uploading it with the FaceBook app and the iPad version of iPhoto and it too looked better!

Answer (score 1):

I think that iPhoto would not give you a choice of photo resolution. Just upload the photos through the Facebook app for iPad.

Comment: The official Facebook app lowers the resolution considerably compared to uploading from the desktop website. This answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is official Facebook answer to your question: https://www.facebook.com/help/266520536764594

You may also consider this option while creating FB album:
https://www.facebook.com/help/187741037945488

Also, if you use Facebook iPad App to upload photos, make sure you have 'Upload HD' option turned on in Facebook iPad App -> Menu (upper left corner) -> Settings -> Videos and Photos -> Upload HD.

You may use any application on iPad (for instance, Snapseed, which is good), however all of them will meet same limitations caused by Facebook policies mentioned above.

Comment: None of this is useful or correct for this question. The first link just tells you the preferred dimensions and file types for FB. The second link only applies to the desktop version of FB. And your note on how to "Upload HD" ONLY applies to VIDEO, and not photos(It says Video right above "Upload HD" in the app).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the official Facebook app?

http://www.facebook.com/mobile/ipad

This allows you to upload pictures directly from your iPad photo library and providing those are of sufficient quality you should be ok.

Comment: The official Facebook app lowers the resolution considerably compared to uploading from the desktop website. This answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Camera app will allow you to upload photos in higher resolution. Most other apps (incl. the offical facebook app) will convert the photo to low res before uploading.

Comment: There is no "Facebook Camera App". This answer is not correct.